# Batch class : Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I have a custom object which has a lookup relationship to Account. There are fields at custom object wherein we have to get the Account Team member values. Our system gets update for AccountTeamMember object from external system. The following batch class on the custom object is to get the latest information from AccountTeamMember for the associated Account. The place where I got stuck is that while executing this code it is exiting as "Attempt to de-reference a null object" which I am not sure why. When I debug the code it is getting all the values but I think somewhere it is failing on the object initialization.

***Batch class***

```
    public class Inquiry_Office_TM_Update_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    Map<Id,AccountTeamMember> atmInfo = new Map<Id,AccountTeamMember>();
    String query,offId,inqID;
    List<Inquiry__c>rmUpdate;
    List<Inquiry__c>rpUpdate;

    public Inquiry_Office_TM_Update_Batch(Map<Id,AccountTeamMember> atmMap){
        this.atmInfo = atmMap;        
    }

    public database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Set<Id> keys = atmInfo.keySet();
        query = 'SELECT Id,Office__c FROM Inquiry__c WHERE Office__c IN: keys';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope){

        for(sObject obj: scope){
            System.debug('@@@objscope:'+scope);
            offId = (String)obj.get('Office__c');
            inqID = (String)obj.get('Id');
            if(atmInfo.containsKey(offId)){
                for(AccountTeamMember atm: atmInfo.values()){
                    String memRole = atm.TeamMemberRole;
                    if(String.isNotBlank(memRole) && memRole == 'Regional Manager'){

                        rmUpdate.add(new Inquiry__c(Id= inqID,Regional_Manager__c = atm.User.Name));                        
                    }
                    if(String.isNotBlank(memRole) && memRole ==  'Regional Partner'){

                        rpUpdate.add(new Inquiry__c(Id= inqID,Regional_Partner__c = atm.User.Name));
                    }
                }
            }            
            if(rmUpdate.size()>0)
             Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(rmUpdate,false);
            if(rpUpdate.size()>0)
                Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(rpUpdate,false);
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }
}
```

**Scheduler Class****

```
public class Inquiry_Office_TM_Update_Scheduler implements Schedulable{

    @ReadOnly
    public void execute(SchedulableContext contxt){
        Set<Id> offIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id,AccountTeamMember> atmMap = new Map<Id,AccountTeamMember>();

        for (Inquiry__c inq:[SELECT Office__c FROM Inquiry__c]){
            offIds.add(inq.Office__c);
        }

        List<AccountTeamMember> atmList = [SELECT AccountId,TeamMemberRole,User.Name FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountId IN: offIds
                                            AND LastModifiedDate = TODAY AND TeamMemberRole IN('Regional Partner','Regional Manager')];
        for(AccountTeamMember atm: atmList){
            atmMap.put(atm.AccountId,atm);
        }

        Inquiry_Office_TM_Update_Batch db = new Inquiry_Office_TM_Update_Batch(atmMap);
        database.executeBatch(db);

    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the text at line 44 of your batch class? SE doesn't show line numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your List variables are never instantiated and thus when you attempt to add things to the the error is thrown.

Easy fix:

Instantiate like this

```
  List<Inquiry__c> rmUpdate = new List<Inquiry__c>();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me to realize the mistake.